# How to make shortest code?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I use the following code to insert multi array to database:

```
foreach($request->category as $k => $v){
                $category[] = array(
                    "category_id" => $v,
                    "announcement_id" => $announcement->id
                );
            }

            AnnouncementCategory::insert($category);
```

So, input data is POST array `$request->category`.
I need  to refactoring this code

I tried this code:

```
$announcement->categories()->attach($request->category);
```

In model `Announcement` I have:

```
 public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\AnnouncementCategory", "announcement_id", "id");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define in your `Announcement` model relationship like this:

```
public function categories() 
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(AnnouncementCategory::class);
}
```

you can do it like this:

```
$announcement->categories()->attach($request->category);
```

**EDIT**

I see you updated your question and added `categories` relationship. But looking at your code, AnnounceCategory is rather pivot table, so you should use `belongsToMany` as I showed instead of `hasMany`

Comment: It should be hasMany, because I work with model `Announcement` where there is `categories`. It does not work

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()

Comment: @Darama Do you have this relationshp defined as `belongsToMany` as I showed in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line if the request matches the columns:

```
AnnouncementCategory::insert($request->all());
```

Then in your `AnnouncementCategory` model, make sure you declare the `protected $fillable` array where you specify which field could be populated.

Comment: But I need to set field `announcement_id` field for each category

Comment: ok, then you can build the array just like you did in your post, I dont see an issue